# Нужно ли шифровать данные?

Tags: android

Нужно ли шифровать данные при отправке их на сервер с клиентского приложения? (Пишу приложение под андроид).

Comment: смотря какие.... ты их сможешь расшифровать на сервере?

Comment: Вот не знаю. Должна, наверное. Мне логин с паролем надо отправить. и параметры заказа ещё. А большая вероятность, что данные могу быть сворованы?

Comment: Если работаете по https, то IMHO не нужно.

Comment: буду пока тогда просто с помощью запроса обычного отправлять)решила, что пока не буду мучиться с шифрованием) всем спасибо за ответы.

Answer (score 2):

[[@Наташенька](/users/5963/%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%88%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%B0)](/users/5963/%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%88%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%B0), уточните какие именно данные и по какому протоколу вы отправляете?
На сегодняшний день структура и принципы работы TCP-IP таковы, что украсть данные имеется возможность, но она не велика и то, только если вы работаете в локальной сети без ограничения доступа. В мобильной сети тоже не удастся, разве что только в поддельной или не зашифрованной, которые найти настолько сложно, что даже пытаться бессмысленно.

Кроме того, чтобы шифровать данные, нужно чтобы сервер их понимал и умел расшифровать.

**UPD**

Дабы не возникало недопонимания, расшифрую следующую фразу "сеть без ограничения доступа". Сие значит, что сеть не имеет возможности обеспечивать на каком-либо из уровней стека TCP/IP сохранности данных, например, привязкой физического порта на коммутаторе к MAC-адресу клиента. Аналогичным считаю невозможность предоставить per-user security в беспроводных сетях. Например, незашифрованные беспроводные сети (вроде халявных хот-спотов), сети с общим ключом доступа и прочие.

К тому же добавлю, что существует ряд протоколов шифрования, которые, по счастливой случайности входят в TCP/IP стек, о коем упоминалось выше, позволяющие шифровать данные от клиента к серверу. Имя тому протоколу - SSL.

Comment: Вы шутите!? Никогда, слышите? Никогда и ни кому больше такого не пишите.

Comment: @Gordio, можете подробнее? Что вам не нравится?

Comment: @Dex, сейчас Вам расскажут о поддельных базовых станциях за 1000$.

Comment: @avp, посмотрим, будет интересно, ведь с одной такой я как раз и работаю:) Хотя, может, мне хотят рассказать о перехвате пакетов чего-то такого, чего я не знаю, в любом случае будет интересно, если есть человеку что мне сказать, с удовольствием прочту и учту все замечания.

Но, я больше склоняюсь к тому, что человек не понял моего повествования и начнет говорить совершенно не о протоколах и методах передачи данных, а возможностях стырить эти данные еще до передачи, или после.

Comment: @Dex, IMHO не дождетесь. 

Последнее время с оценками вообще какая-то дурь происходит. Например, вчера ответ

    system("C:\\адрес\\файла\\файл.html");

минуснули 2 раза, а ответ

    system ("start c:\\users\\avp\\ttt.htm");

(на тот же вопрос) не тронули.

Comment: Думаю, речь шла про хот-споты, кои достаточно часто используются смартфонами.

Comment: Какая разница о чем шла речь?

1. Если она решила не шифровать значит не все так критично.
2. А если шифровать от провайдера, то да, это я упустил, хотя мне казалось, что писал.
3. Ну и в конце-концов https тоже является частью стека tcp/ip....

Comment: Видимо вы не так меня поняли.

@Dex
> В мобильной сети тоже не удастся, разве что только в поддельной или не зашифрованной, которые найти настолько сложно, что даже пытаться бессмысленно.

По мимо мобильной сети, есть бесплатные хот-споты, которые, надо сказать, весьма популярны. В этом случае украсть данные очень даже возможно.

Comment: Если бы смартфоны были на одном только 3G...

Реалистичный юзкейс один: телефон дома, зацепился на wifi-роутер. Роутер подключен через metroethernet с pppoe. Труди топает в подъезд, выдергивает джек из розетки и развлекается как хочет.

Реалистичный юзкейс джва: телефон в макдачной зацепился на публичный хотспот. Ева сидит за соседним столиком с ноутбуком.

Comment: Неужели фраза "сеть без ограничения доступа" настолько непонятна? Имелись ввиду все типы сетей в которых пользователи имеют возможность перехватить трафик. Это и сети на базе wired-ethernet, где можно использовать активный снифер, спуфинг и прочее. Это и сети wireless, с возможностью сниффинга, паролями wep и др.

Если у вас есть per-user policy вы ничего не сделаете.

С единственным я согласен - это провайдер, который может видеть трафик. В данном случае переходим на ssl-based connection, как писал @avp.

**See UPD**

Comment: Я про то, что сетей, в которых получить проходящие данные, тривиально — слишком много, они буквально на каждом шагу. Роутеры с WEP или тривиальными/дефолтными паролями, ничем не защищенная витуха в слаботочках, открытые хотспоты — куда ни плюнь, везде они. Поэтому украсть данные (не прицельно для конкретного пользователя, а просто собирая в черный мешок весь трафик, что найдется) достаточно просто. А HTTPS или SSL/TLS это уже таки шифрование.

Answer (score 0):

Зависит от важности отправляемых данных. Если это персональные данные - то бесспорно нужно, если это просто число - то смысл?